# Constants in Meyer inequalities

Tags: probability, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

Let us first recall Meyer inequality in the Malliavin calculus framework
$$\|\delta(u)\|_{L^p}\leq C_p\|u\|_{\mathbb{D}^{1,p}},\qquad \forall u\in \mathbb{D}^{1,p},$$
where $\delta$ is the skorohod integral, $\mathbb{D}^{1,p}$ is the Sobolev space, and $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{D}^{1,p}}$ is given by:
$$\|u\|_{\mathbb{D}^{1,p}}=\mathbb{E}[\|u\|^p_H]+\mathbb{E}[\|Du\|^p_{H\otimes H}],$$
here $D$ denotes the Malliavin derivatives. I want to estimate the constants $C_p$ for $p$ large enough, i.e., I want some thing like $C_p=O(p^{\beta})$.

Comment: Maybe you want to post this interesting question in the more specialized site [MO](https://mathoverflow.net). Here, there are capable people who can answer your question, but unfortunately, you may have to add a few lines to your posting explaining why this is relevant to you, where the problems comes from, etc. Here are some guidelines for posting questions at [MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/121671). Although you give clear definitions, still some people will complain about "context" and vote to close your question. Again, MO is probably a better place for your question.

Comment: @Mohamed: You have posted this question on MO, and then deleted it. I suggest that you undelete it (I even voted to reopen it). Its first version was, frankly, quite poor, but the revised one was good. I believe that the level of this question is too technical for MSE, while on MO it would be at home. Also, "Skorohod" is with a "capital S", being a Russian name.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior (and sharpness) of $C_{p}$ is studied in "Riesz transforms : a simpler analytic proof of P. A. Meyer’s inequality".

For example, on page 487 they claim

$$C_{p}\in O(p)\text{ as }p\to +\infty\text{ and }C_{p}\in O(\frac{1}{p-1})\text{ as }p\to 1.$$